# Cloud functions user session

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create user sessions via Google Cloud Functions (Express-session).

Since no storage is available by default, I'm looking for the best (cheapest/easiest) solution to save my session data.

In this list, the supported services are listed: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services

I've tried SQL but this is not available as a service, BigTable/Spanner requires continues uptime (= not cheap), Firebase looks quite complex and DataStore is not available since I have no App Engine.

Can someone point me into the right direction? It's just a hobby project so it does not have to scale hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datastore with Cloud Function, see e.g., [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@chriswrite/cloud-function-and-datastore-tutorial-intro-to-build-a-server-less-service-92bc106ef8e5). AppEngine is definitely not a prerequisite for using Datastore.

I'd recommend Firestore, though. The client library is more intuitive in my opinion and Firestore is strongly consistent.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to visit the Google Cloud webpage dedicated to choose the [storage option](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) that best suits your present and future needs, which you know better. Just follow the schema. Check the “pricing” for your chosen products (e.g.: I would choose [DataStore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) or [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing)).

You can use DataStore without deploying App Engine services, so it is also an option.